# How to create image QR Barcode and save it to google drives from google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

I am generating QR codes in a column in Google Sheets with data entered via a Google Forms, and I would like to save them as images.

I'm want to generate QR Code in a row in Google Sheets, and I would like to save them as images.
I cant copy the image generated by this function :

```
=image("https://image-charts.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&choe=UTF-8&chl="&ENCODEURL(B2))
```

Using Ctrl + C and Ctrl+V works only inside the Google Sheet and trying to copy and paste that one outside the sheet doesn't work either. The clipboard is detected as not containing images to paste elsewhere.

The problem is not in generating the QR, but exporting or saving it as an image to a folder in google drives. And I want the naming to be the links where the image (QR code) is generated, and the Column and row name to make sure that the image is the right QR Code Pictures.

I think this is can be accomplished by using google apps script

This is the  [Samples Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ARg0uNswZ7Llbf5V8ejL1GOXYpwYRyecxOhvGgOf9Pg/edit#gid=0)
This is the  [Folder Link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ZVYsJ-gACejcgp5swgn_GLIgMNMTSB1c?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
function uploadFile() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var datas = sh.getRange('B2:B' + sh.getLastRow()).getValues()
  datas.forEach(function (data) {
    if (data != '') {
      var imgurl = "https://image-charts.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&choe=UTF-8&chl=" + encodeURI(data)
      var image = UrlFetchApp.fetch(imgurl).getBlob().getAs('image/jpeg').setName(data);
      var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('________your folder id_____');
      var file = DriveApp.createFile(image);
      Drive.Files.update({ "parents": [{ "id": folder.getId() }] }, file.getId());
    }
  })
}
```

enable drive api and put your folder id inside the script

or, put checkboxes in column A and put a trigger for this function

```
function uploadQRCode(event) {
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if (s.getName() == "Sheet1" && r.getColumn() == 1 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var imgurl = "https://image-charts.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&choe=UTF-8&chl=" + encodeURI(r.offset(0,1).getValue())
    var image = UrlFetchApp.fetch(imgurl).getBlob().getAs('image/jpeg').setName(r.offset(0,1).getValue());
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('________your folder id_____');
    var file = DriveApp.createFile(image);
    Drive.Files.update({"parents": [{"id": folder.getId()}]}, file.getId());
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('QRCode "'+r.offset(0,1).getValue()+'" saved !')
  }
}
```

Comment: i want it to be every column on row b, not only in range B2. And I want the naming to be the link. I have tried your code, but error : ReferenceError: Drive is not defined
uploadFile @ Code.gs:11

Comment: pls, enable drive api : click on service on the left hand side of the script editor

Comment: the name is now the parameter of the link .. but i don't understand what you mean by `every column on row b`

Comment: i have changed b2 to b2:b5, but the result is only 1 pictures only sir. And how to rename the picure?

Comment: can you share a simplified spreadsheet? thx

Comment: i have shared the spreadsheet example on my questions sir, its on the bottom

Comment: ok, I have updated my answer